# How to add a python program to the bootup menu?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, reboot

I got a program which I want to add to the reboot start up menu so that when I switch on my PC (Win 7) it will start automatically.
The program collects data about my usage of internet if that is relevant (I have a bet with a friend on how many hours a day I am connected to the internet.)
Thank you

Comment: make a batch file , from that call python and put the batch file in startup folder

Comment: Or use the task scheduler tool to run your script on startup

Comment: I know I can do that but I want to do it directly from the code. Is there a way?

Comment: No. But of course, your python script can generate a batch file itself and place it in the startup folder.